How to create a .bin file for a chess opening book?
I'm working on a chess project and need to create a .bin file for a chess opening book. I've gathered that tools like PolyGlot can be used for this purpose, but I'm not entirely sure of the steps involved.
Specifically, I'm looking for:

The tools or software required to create a .bin file for chess.

Instructions on how to merge multiple PGN files if I want to include hundreds of openings.


